# How to make Gmail like loading progress bar

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax

I want create a loading progress bar like Gmail in center and top of the page, 
and work in all browsers

Comment: welcome to SO. Generally people are more willing to help if you can break your problem down into smaller pieces, and if you show what work you've done so far and where you're having problems with it. Best of luck to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmail-style progress bar when page is loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020929/gmail-style-progress-bar-when-page-is-loading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0px;
            }
            #state{
                width:100px;
                height:30px;
                background:#FEE27C;
                position:fixed !important; 
                position:absolute /* fallback for IE6 */;
            }
        </style>
        <script language=javascript type='text/javascript' >
            function set(){
                var s = screen_now_size();
                margin_right = (s['width']-100)/2;

                //append or change margin right size
                var state_layer = document.getElementById("state");
                state_layer.style.right      = margin_right+"px"
            }

            function screen_now_size(){ // get screen current size
                var a=new Array();
                if(typeof document.compatMode!='undefined'&&document.compatMode!='BackCompat'){
                  a["width"]=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                  a["height"]=document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.body.clientHeight;
                }else{
                  a["width"]=document.body.clientWidth;
                  a["height"]=document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight;
                  }
                return a;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='set()'>
        <div id='state'></div>
        <!--for test:-->
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        for test
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery UI Progressbar plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar).  As your page loads the data it needs, update the value of the progress bar.

Comment: @MSI Please reword your question to clearly state what you are looking for.  As your question stands, the only mention of ajax is in one of your tags.

Answer (score 2):

You sir need to use `$(document).ajaxStart()` and `$(document).ajaxStop()` to achieve that with jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

This might be not exactly what your looking for, but it will help you get started:
http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a mix of jQueryUI ProgressBar and jQuery FancyBox which can hold content (like a progressbar).