# Gmail-style progress bar when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show a loading/progress bar to show how far along that the page is loaded? I want something like Gmail's:

[image]

I am using jQuery so it would be great if there is some jQuery code that can show the percentage of how far along the page has loaded.

Comment: Didn't you blank out the wrong part of that email? I'm pretty sure I can guess the rest :-)

Comment: Maybe it's a Google Apps account :)

Comment: @MarkEmbling You're right, it is :) I was going to tell nilskp that but I forgot about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you want, see example, you can also download it and tweak as your needs:

[Jquery Pre Loader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks! So I wont have to specify everything that is needed to load? By the way, there is [a newer version](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/) of QueryLoader, it says _"There is a new version of QueryLoader. Consider this one obsolete!"_ on the first version.

Comment: No worries. you ca use the newer version. Glad it helped.