# How to show a gmail look alike blue colored progress bar instead of loader-icon image in following PHP, jQuery-AJAX implementation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm using `Bootstrap v3.3.5` in my website.

The is one form which sends the AJAX request to PHP file for adding data to the database. While this request is processed it shows a loader-icon image. Instead of this loader-icon image I want to show a gmail look alike blue colored progress bar. But I'm not able to show it, so please help me.

Following is the necessary code which currently displays the loader-icon image during AJAX request processing.

```
<style>#loader-icon {top: 50%;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;display:none;}</style>
<div id="loader-icon"><img src="{$user_img_url}/LoaderIcon.gif" /></div>
```

Comment: The progress bar implementation requires more code than pure CSS. Have you solved that part yet?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:No. Actually I'd added my code to this question but might be stack is facing some issue so I'm not able to add my code to question body. It'd be great if you could post the code in answer.

Comment: similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986871/how-to-make-gmail-like-loading-progress-bar